# Mole Stub and Attributes

Tags: moles

I am creating a Unit Test for a certain method that loads all the types that was decorated by a `PluginAttribute`.

Instead of manually creating a stub and decorating it with PluginAttribute, is there a way to "inject" an attribute on the Moles generated stub object?

```
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {

                    var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(PluginAttribute), false) as PluginAttribute;
                    if (attr != null)
                    {
                        _checksLookup.Add(attr.ElementName, t);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Moles you can detour the `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` method so that it returns a new instance of `PluginAttribute` when it gets the stub type on input or falls back to the default implementation otherwise.